# My class-objects disappears when doing the next request to my API (InMemoryDb)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) while creating an API and come across an issue I struggle to solve:

I have two model-classes: Todo and TodoItem.

I have put an ICollection of TodoItems inside the Todo-class.

When I am to return the Todo's from an API GET request, it works the first time but as soon as a second request is sent, the TodoItem collection is overwritten and declared once more through the constructor of Todo.

- Tried some annotations (ForeignKey).
- Adding a list of TodoItemIds inside Todo
  (TodoItemIds type = new class with Id and the TodoItemId).
- Storing Todo and TodoId inside of TodoItem.
- Tried to add some code to OnModelcreating() in TodoContext (modelBuilder.Entity<>()...).

Here is the controller code, I don't know how to paste it in nicely...:

**TodoController**

```cs
public TodoController(TodoContext context){
    _context = context;

    if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
    {
        // Create a new TodoItem if collection is empty,
        // which means you can't delete all TodoItems.
        _context.Todos.Add(new Todo(new TodoItem("Walk the dog")));
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

// GET: api/Todo
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Todo>>> GetTodo()
{
    return await _context.Todos.ToListAsync();
}
```

**TodoContext**

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Todo>()
        .HasMany(t => t.TodoItems);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**First Get-Request-Response**

```
[
    {
        "id": "34bfd453-8f06-4733-a4b6-1fb209327a8d",
        "todoItems": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Walk the dog",
                "isComplete": false,
                "todoId": "34bfd453-8f06-4733-a4b6-1fb209327a8d"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Second Get-Request-Response**

```
 [
     {
        "id": "34bfd453-8f06-4733-a4b6-1fb209327a8d",
        "todoItems": []
     }
 ]
```

The todoItems-list should not disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load `Todo.TodoItems` from the database.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Todo>>> GetTodo()
{
    return await _context.Todos.Include(t => t.TodoItems).ToListAsync();
}
```

Above code uses Eager Loading, `Include(t => t.TodoItems)`, but there are different ways to [load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) using EF Core.

The reason there's a `TodoItem` the first time is because it was just added to the `TodoContext` so it is still loaded on that particular `TodoContext` instance.

Comment: Wow that is awesome, it said I should avoid to say thank you but - THANK YOU!!!!! This is incredibly understandable thanks to your presentation. 

It feels like this is something "basic" for Entity Framework but I have totally missed it. Thank you again and have a good evening. I will read that link. :)